# Default form action isn't working in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, phpstorm

I am new to magento, I created the button in `magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml` for sending emails for quote information. It's showing the button and When customer click on quote button I redirected my custom action
that is `getUrl('wishlist/quote/index')`

```
<form id="wishlist-view-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/update', array('wishlist_id' => $this->getWishlistInstance()->getId())) ?>" method="post">
            ....
                <div>
                    <button class="form-button" type="submit" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('wishlist/quote/index'); ?>')"><span>Submit</span></button>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

but it's not working. By default, this form is firing  `$this->getUrl('*/*/update', array('wishlist_id' => $this->getWishlistInstance()->getId()))` form action.

and I created controller in `Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\controllers\QuoteController.php`

```
<?php

class Mage_Wishlist_QuoteController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        Mage::log("customer");

        ....

        $this->_redirect('wishlist/index/index');
    }

}
```

and `Magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\wishlist.xml`

```
<wishlist_quote_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="customer.mail" type="wishlist/mail_email" template="wishlist/test.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </wishlist_quote_index>
```

why magento act like this? If I redirect using custom button how can I redirect/send/do some action?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you press button it submits the form and is not setting location. Just set form action  `wishlist/quote/index`. If button purpose is to submit form use action. If purpose is just redirect to some page use a link button.

### Update:

For setting different submit url's for different buttons use:

```
onclick="editForm.submit('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('wishlist/quote/index'); ?>');return false;"
```

editForm - here is object which is creating to validate form. It should be defined in somewhere in `magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml`. If not define it

```
var editForm = new varienForm('wishlist-view-form');
```

Comment: in `indexAction()` I redirected but it's not calling the action defaultly it's calling form action why?

Comment: Because it is html standard behavior. Just set correct form action.

Comment: how can you suggest me? or post some of code it will be better for me.

Comment: `<form id="wishlist-view-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('wishlist/quote/index') ?>" method="post">`

Comment: In this form 4+1(custom button)=5 buttons is there so I want work every button as indusal how?